# React Native navigate

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation

So I saw a lot of tutorials with "build in" (React Navigation) components and tools like Bottom Tab bar, etc.! But even if it sounds weird I want to make everything on my own.
I do not want weird navigation with a header and than I can swipe to the side and it all looks native, etc.! I want to have like an `<a></a>` tag to navigate around. So I think in Html it would look like this:

```
<a href="./home.html">Home</a>
```

Is there any chance to get this working in React Native? It's not a problem for me to use librarys for helping to navigate but e.g. with React Navigation it all looks so Native - and I do not want this! :) Maybe anybody can help me with my issue? :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Henrik, I would suggest you using the `createBottomTabNavigator` from React Navigation, you can read more here [reactnavigation.org/docs/bottom-tab-navigator](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/bottom-tab-navigator/)